# Screen Sharing / Linux

Tags: remote-desktop

I work with a developer oversees and we use Skype for screen sharing currently.

After about 10 to 20 minutes of sharing, the screen starts to lag to a point where it is unusable and we need to restart the session.

Is there another Linux compatible screen sharing solution that provides better performance?  Even if the quality of the stream is reduced because of the distance, that would be fine.

Comment: Have look at a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) solution like [realvnc](http://realvnc.com). Don't know if realvnc works on linux but there are a ton of other vnc client for linux. Vote to migrate to superuser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also look at [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)

Comment: THis works rerally well anjd is very fast!  Best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must install remote desktop server and client. There are 4 possibilities:

1. RDP
2. VNC
3. Using X server over ethernet
4. Teamview

Comment: I used remote desktop over VNC (for some reason SSH isnt working) for ubuntu and it was very slow.

Comment: Teamviewer is the best option here

Answer (score 0):

There's always vnc, but it does not have any of the other conference features that skype has. You will need to install a vnc server on the computer that you want to share, and install a vnc client on the other computer. You will also need to make sure that your firewall allows vnc.

Comment: voice on skype works fine.  Could possibly use a combo of things..

Answer (score 0):

I think VNC doesn't cut it either, it's slooooooooooooooooow as hell. [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) client is the best I've seen for Linux. You can install [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) on the Linux boxes that you want access using remote desktop connection from either the Windows client or the Linux one (rdesktop referenced above).

Comment: Rdesktop is obsolete. As I remember, tsclient is newer.

Comment: @George Gaál thanks! There you go bryan_ruiz, use tsclient+xrdp.

Comment: slower than skype

Comment: @bryan_ruiz I am afraid that you won't find anything better, at least not a free product for Linux.

Comment: found something better... team viewer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try an [NX client-server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) solution which will work in Linux and won't be as slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at one called [mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com/), which seems to work alright.